# python: using output from method's class inside another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to develop my first app with PyQt5 (a memory game).

I have created two classes: **MainApplication**, which inherits from QMainWindow, and **GridWidget**, which inherits from QWidget. My aim is to let the user specify a folder with some images (jpg) using the fileMenu of the menuBar.

So, in the **MainApplication** I created the method **showDialog** which connects to the fileMenu and outputs a list of filenames (names of the images within the selected folder), stored in a list variable. I would like to be able to pass this to the **GridWidget**, so that it can creates and fill the grid.

I am kind of new to OOP programming, so maybe the organization of my script is not the best, and I am open to suggestions to improve it. My idea was to add **GridWidget** into **MainApplication**, but I don't know how to pass the output of **showDialog** to this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Memory game 

My first memory game in PyQt5.

author: Umberto Minora 
last edited: September 2016
"""

import os, sys, glob
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget,
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QAction, QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class MainApplication(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction('Open', self)
        openFile.setStatusTip('Search image folder')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.form_widget = GridWidget(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Memory Game!')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):

        folder = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory", 
            '/home', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

        images = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.jpg'))

        if images:
            return images * 2

class GridWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        names = self.showDialog() # DA SISTEMARE!!!!!!

        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(int(len(names)/2)) for j in range(int(len(names)/2))]

        for position, name in zip(positions, names):

            if name == '':
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            grid.addWidget(button, *position)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApplication()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to **@ekhumoro**'s answer, now the code is working. Here is the code I am actually running (it's not the complete game, just an initial import of images from a folder).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Memory game 2

My first memory game in PyQt5.

author: Umberto Minora 
last edited: September 2016
"""

import os, sys, glob, math
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget,
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QAction, QFileDialog, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class MainApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction('Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Search image folder')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.gridWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gridWidget)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Memory Game!')
        self.show()

    def populateGrid(self, images):
        names = images * 2
        n_cols = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(names)))
        n_rows = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(names)))
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(n_cols) for j in range(n_rows)]
        for position, name in zip(positions, names):
            if name == '':
                continue
            pixmap = QPixmap(name)
            scaled = pixmap.scaled(pixmap.width()/3, pixmap.height()/3)
            del(pixmap)
            lbl = QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(scaled)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(lbl, *position)

    def showDialog(self):
        folder = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory",
            '.', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

        images = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.jpg'))

        if images:
            self.populateGrid(images)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApplication()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be simpler if you keep everything in one class. You should make each child widget an attribute of the class, so you can access them later using `self` within the methods of the class. All the program logic will go in the methods - so it's just a matter of calling methods in response to signals and events.

Here is what the class should look like:

```
class MainApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction('Open', self)
        openFile.setStatusTip('Search image folder')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.gridWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gridWidget)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Memory Game!')
        self.show()

    def populateGrid(self, images):
        names = images * 2
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(int(len(names)/2)) for j in range(int(len(names)/2))]
        for position, name in zip(positions, names):
            if name == '':
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(button, *position)

    def showDialog(self):
        folder = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory",
            '/home', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

        images = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.jpg'))

        if images:
            self.populateGrid(images)
```