# PyQt5: updating MainApplication layout after QAction through widget method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create my first memory game.

I recently found out how to have it working thanks to the answer of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689134/python-using-output-from-methods-class-inside-another-class/39689457#39689457). The working code is posted in the same link, but now I am trying to keep the widgets and the main application classes separated 1) because I think it's better, and 2) because I would like to in order to learn better how OOP works.

So, I here post my new code, which seems to work except the very last part. The concept:

1. **MainApplication** has a menubar which permits to path to a folder of images, and instantiate the **MemoryGame** widget, which in turns initializes an empty QGridLayout.
2. Clicking File -> open in the menubar the method **showDialog** is called.
3. When a folder is chosen, **populate_grid** method (of MemoryGame obj) is called.
4. **populate_grid** "should" fill the QGridLayout with each of the image found.
5. The grid should be displayed to the screen, but it's not....

I am pretty sure the problem is in the very final row of **populate_grid**, where I add elements to the grid layout, but I can't find out how to solve the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Memory game 3

My first memory game in PyQt5.

author: Umberto Minora 
last edited: September 2016
"""

import os
import sys
import glob
import math

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget,
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QAction, QFileDialog, QLabel)

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class MainApplication(QMainWindow):
    """This is the main application.
    All widgets should be put inside it."""
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = widget
        self.initUI()

    def showDialog(self):
        folder = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory",
            '.', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

        images = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.jpg'))

        if images:
            self.widget.populate_grid(images)

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction('Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Search image folder')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Memory Game!')
        self.show()

class MemoryGame(QWidget):
    """This is the Memory Game Widget"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.gridWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridWidget)

    def populate_grid(self, images):
        n_cols = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(images)))
        n_rows = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(images)))
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(n_cols) for j in range(n_rows)]
        for position, img in zip(positions, images):
            if img == '':
                continue
            pixmap = QPixmap(img)
            scaled = pixmap.scaled(pixmap.width()/3, pixmap.height()/3)
            del(pixmap)
            lbl = QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(scaled)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(lbl, *position)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApplication(MemoryGame())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the images aren't showing is because you put the `gridWidget` inside the `MemoryGame` widget, which doesn't have a layout itself. The `MemoryGame` widget should actually *replace* the `gridWidget`, so all you need to do is this:

```
class MemoryGame(QWidget):
    """This is the Memory Game Widget"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
```

I also think the way you create the `MemoryGame` widget is unnecessarily convoluted. Custom widget classes should be treated like any other. There's no need to pass it into the `MainApplication` constructor like that - just create it directly inside `initUi`:

```
def initUI(self):
    ...        
    self.widget = MemoryGame()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

Comment: Thanks again! Anyway, imagine I would like to implement my MainApplication with other games (e.g. PokerGame). Wouldn't it be better to separate the main application from its (let's say) child widgets? Of course, now my MainApplication is super simple, I am more thinking about how it would potentially become.

Comment: If you want multiple games, each game should be entirely self-contained (i.e. with everything in one class, as I suggested earlier). Currently, your memory game is split over two classes, each of which cannot function without the other. With multiple games, each game would also need to provide it's own specialised menus. So the main application would be responsible for loading the game's main widget and showing the game's menus in the main menubar, but the game would do everything else. The games should have a generic interface, and the main application should just treat them as "black boxes".